# How to get data that is older than 6 weeks from GCP metrics explorer API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using GCP's monitoring API(below) to fetch the usage data of Cloud Storage buckets.

```
"https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects"
```

With this I'm able to fetch data that is only 6 weeks old, how will I be able to fetch data that is older than 6 weeks?

Answer (score 1):

By Default monitoring API stores data only up to 6 weeks only. If you need data for more than 6 weeks or long term data then as per [data retention policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quotas#data_retention_policy) you can extend up to 24 months. There is no additional cost for this extended retention policy. Refer to this [extended-retention blog by Rory Petty & Shishi Chen](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/extended-retention-times-for-custom-cloud-monitoring-metrics/) times for custom cloud-monitoring-metrics for more information.

Comment: is it 24 months by default ? I tried to create a metric descriptor and push timeseries custom metric using [link](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/monitoring/latest/google.cloud.monitoring_v3.services.metric_service.MetricServiceClient) but still i only see 6 weeks in the time picker.

Comment: by default it is k weeks only if you need to extend then you can follow the extended-retention doc given in answer .. by that you can extend upto 24 months.

Comment: thanks.. but i do not see any option to increase it in the document. It is mentioned `Extended retention for custom and Prometheus metrics is enabled by default.` But in metric explorer time picker it does not give me an option to choose more than 6 weeks.

Comment: As per this [doc](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11004084?hl=en) I'am able to select for 24 months, can you try by following this doc.

Comment: Think it is a different product and i am able to select 24 months in analytics, but the actual issue is with GCP metric explorer [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-explorer). Not sure whether its because i have data only for last one week, but wanted to confirm that it can retain the data for 24 months

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/monitoring/metrics-scopes/create) of how to fetch historical data there is no **free** way to achieve this.

You have to create a **custom time-series** with a retention period (lets say 365 days) using the gcloud command-line tool:

```
gcloud beta monitoring metric descriptors create \
--project=[PROJECT_ID] \
--type=custom.googleapis.com/storage/usage \
--metric-kind=GAUGE \
--value-type=DOUBLE \
--description="Custom storage usage metric" \
--unit="bytes" \
--display-name="Custom Storage Usage" \
--metadata=kind=storage,resource=storage_bucket \
--retention=365d
```

**Caution!** Keep in mind that for longer retention periods Google may include additional costs, so you should consider the costs before implementing this solution. Maybe try it with 1 month retention first.